# Word Fill VBA in MS Access for various fields in table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, form-fields

For our incident management side of our database I am trying to have data from fields in my table(s) generate within the 149 Investigative Report, a Word document template provided by the state ([see link here](https://opwdd.ny.gov/sites/default/files/documents/OPWDD_149_Instructions_post_2.pdf)).

I made a read-only version of the document to preserve its integrity by forcing a save as by the user and loaded it with text form fields with bookmarks to reference (example: `txtcaseintroduction`).

I modified code I found in the internet for working with form fields and assigned it to a button on one of my forms to assist in generating the report (the `Open` reference is modified for security reasons):

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()

'Export 149 Report.

Dim appWord As Word.Application

Dim doc As Word.Document

'Avoid error 429, when Word isn't open.

On Error Resume Next

Err.Clear

'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.

Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.

Set appWord = New Word.Application

End If

Set doc = appWord.Documents.Add("Y:\ABC\2018\Case Files\2018 - Incident Forms\OPWDD 149 - Access Database Reference.docx", , True)

With doc
    .FormFields("txtNIMRS").Result = Me.NIMRSID
    .FormFields("txtInternalID").Result = Me.InternalIncidentID
    .FormFields("txtIncidentDate").Result = Me.[IncidentOccurrenceDate]
    .FormFields("txtDiscoverydate").Result = Me.[IncidentReportDate]
    .FormFields("txtCaseIntroduction").Result = Me.CaseIntroduction
    .FormFields("txtIncidentLocation").Result = Me.Location
    .FormFields("txtBackground").Result = Me.BackgroundInfo
    .FormFields("txtProtections").Result = Me.ImmedProtec
    .FormFields("txtQuestion").Result = Me.InvestQuestion
    .FormFields("txtTestName").Result = Me.[TestimonialEvidence]
    .FormFields("txtDocumentaryE").Result = Me.[DocumentaryEvidence]
    .FormFields("txtDemonstrativeE").Result = Me.[DemonstrativeEvidence]
    .FormFields("txtPhysicalE").Result = Me.[PhysicalEvidence]
    .FormFields("txtWSName").Result = Me.[WrittenStatements]
    .FormFields("txtSummary").Result = Me.SummaryEvidence
    .FormFields("txtConclusions").Result = Me.Text409
    .FormFields("txtRecommendations").Result = Me.Text411
    .FormFields("txtInvestigator").Result = Me.Investigator_s__Assigned
    .FormFields("txtdatereport").Result = Me.Investigative_Report_Completion_Date
.Visible = True

.Activate

End With

Set doc = Nothing

Set appWord = Nothing

Exit Sub

errHandler:

MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

The following fields work:

```
 .FormFields("txtNIMRS").Result = Me.NIMRSID
        .FormFields("txtInternalID").Result = Me.InternalIncidentID
        .FormFields("txtIncidentDate").Result = Me.[IncidentOccurrenceDate]
        .FormFields("txtDiscoverydate").Result = Me.[IncidentReportDate]
.FormFields("txtIncidentLocation").Result = Me.Location
        .FormFields("txtBackground").Result = Me.BackgroundInfo
        .FormFields("txtProtections").Result = Me.ImmedProtec
        .FormFields("txtQuestion").Result = Me.InvestQuestion
 .FormFields("txtConclusions").Result = Me.Text409
        .FormFields("txtRecommendations").Result = Me.Text411
.FormFields("txtdatereport").Result = Me.Investigative_Report_Completion_Date
```

The remaining fields (`case introduction`, `investigator`, and the attachment fields) do not. All of these fields exist on the same table. It is also noted that case introduction used to work, but stopped working as I tried to figure out more form fields to apply to the document and reference. The goal was to have the investigator essentially do all of their work in the database and then export it to the required format for submission to the state.

**My question**: what do I need to do to the above code to get the non-working fields functional in populating the Word document?

**Responding to questions in comments**

- No error that occurs; the text-boxes are simply not populating when I engage the button.
- The form fields do not need to be present in the result document. They are simply "targets" for the data.

Comment: First thing, this document should be used *as a template*, not as a document set as "read-only". Use `appWord.Documents.Add("PathToOriginalFile")` - this creates a *copy* of the original as a new document so there's no chance of it being changed.

Comment: Correct - to the question at the end of your comment. The reason you aren't seeing any errors is because error notifcations are disabled by `On Error Resume Next`. Put `On Error GoTo 0` after the line with `GetObject`, then test again.

Comment: So I saved the document as a .doctm file to allow the template to enable macros and changed the file source in the VBA to reflect the change, but Access still wasn't able to locate it. I put it back to the .docx read only version and it was able to find the file. Not sure what's happening there that it won't locate the new file. I also made the changes you recommended in your last comment regarding Errors; without the error code suppressed, the VBA returned that the CaseIntroduction string is "too long." Should I shorten the bookmark name of the form field textbox?

Comment: There's no such thing as  a ".doctm" file format... But in any case, no need to change the file type or extension: just use the `Add` rather than the `Open`method.

Comment: There is a limit to the number of characters that can be used as a bookmark name, although I would have expected the Word application would not have accepted it, had that been the problem. More likely, it's the amount of data the code is trying to write to the form field. If you test by shortening that will it work?

Comment: .dotm* my apologies. All the same, I have made the change you recommended. When i shortened the amount of characters within the field, it was able to transfer with no problems. I did some research yesterday and saw that once the amount of characters the code tries to transfer exceeds 255 characters, the transfer will not occur. Is there a way to bypass this limit?

Comment: Word has, for some things, a built-in limit of 255 characters. (Word is, technologically, *very* old - going on 30 years!) Question: Do you need to re-use the form fields or can they disappear when the data is written?

Comment: Hi again @Cindy Meister (i don't think I did this right lol); the form fields can disappear when the data is written. Once the information is transferred, in theory, the report should be done. Any edits that would be required would have been made in the Form where the investigator writes the investigative report and then transferred to Word once completed. I had developed a spellcheck button in the form to help investigators with that so they knew what to do prior to generating the Word report. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly then, yes, you understood me correctly :-) In this case, you would not need to use form fields, although they make a "comfortable" target. Bookmarks or ContentControls would do just as well. Indeed, a form field name *is* a bookmark. Since the reports already have form fields, my suggestion at this point is to look at not 1) not using Forms protection; 2) don't target FormField.Result, just the bookmark's `Range`, which should essentially remove the form field.

Comment: Check my edits - done to make this more understandable/useful for future visitors who may have the same issue - to make sure I haven't made an unintended mistake. Also, if you have the time, could you edit in the version of your code that uses `Documents.Add`, please? This, so that others who may copy this code pick up the "better" approach for forcing users to work with a copy of a document. (And please do *not* incorporate my answer - Stack Overflow doesn't work that way.) With that done, comments can be thinned out even more, improving the usefulness of the contribution :-)

Comment: Thank you so much Cindy; I made the edit and switched the code to Documents.Add as recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the form fields do not need to be retained in the result document the simplest approach would be to simply insert the data to the `FormField.Range`, which will replace (remove) the form field. The entire code can be written in this manner if consistency is important (how the end result looks to the user), but from a *programming* stand-point need not be.

Note: If Forms protection is activated, it needs to be turned off for this approach to work

```
If doc.ProtectionType <> -1 Then doc.Unprotect  '-1 = wdNoProtection
```

Sample code line for a string longer than 255 characters

```
.FormFields("txtCaseIntroduction").Range = Me.CaseIntroduction
```

Comment: This was the solution! Thank you so much!